# Show only the First Row of a Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

this query shows a list of actors and how many times they acted in an action-type movie between 1980 and 2000. I'd like to get only the first rows but I didn't find an answer to my question.
Moreover, tell me if there is a better solution for my query.

FILM (**CODFILM**,TITLE,YEAR,GENRE)
ACTOR (**CODACTOR**,NAME,SURNAME)
CAST (**CODFILM**,**CODACTOR**)

YEAR type is Number and it's write-only the year release

```
SELECT CODACTOR, GENRE,count(CODACTOR) 
FROM FILM NATURAL JOIN CAST T
WHERE GENRE = 'Action' AND YEAR BETWEEN 1980 AND 2000 
GROUP BY CODACTOR,GENRE 
HAVING COUNT(CODACTOR) >= ALL( 
SELECT COUNT(CODACTOR) 
FROM FILM NATURAL JOIN CAST
WHERE GENRE = 'Action' AND CODACTOR = T.CODACTOR AND ANNO BETWEEN 1980 AND 2000) 
ORDER BY COUNT(CODACTOR) DESC;
```

Comment: version of Oracle? cause if 12 or higher...append this to your query - fetch first 1 rows only

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your query

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-3412F450-D7EB-4DC8-8888-60CABF592AD4)

Example -

Top 3 compensated employees

[image]

This is available in version 12 and higher of the database.

Below that you could use pseudo column, ROWNUM